# Different :hover for first link in a list

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

My HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If I write

```
nav ul li a:hover{}
```

It will create `hover` for all links.

How to create sentence that first link `"Link1"` will have different hover?

Comment: `nav ul li:first-child a:hover { }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)** pseudo-selector

```css
nav ul li:first-child a:hover {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```